# Last digit of a perfect square must be $0, 1, 4, 5, 6,$ or $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that a perfect square number can contain 0,1,4,5,6 and 9 in its unit place.

How can I prove that a perfect square number cannot contain 2,3,7 and 8 in its unit place?

Comment: The unit place of $x^2$ depends only on the unit place of $x$.  How many cases are there for the unit place of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compute the remainder when you divide the square of each possible digit by 10. Then these are the only possible values for the last digit you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch

You can express any integer in the form $10n\pm r$ with $0\le r \le 5$

Then $(10n\pm r)^2=10\cdot(10n^2\pm 2nr)+r^2$

The final digit of the square will be the final digit of $r^2$, for which there are just six possibilities.